# How to invoke /api/auth/{provider} as a popup (ajax) rather than a full post?

Tags: servicestack

I am looking to replace a toolkit that does social auth through a seamless popup, where the entry point is a javascript function and there are javascript callbacks that you install that pass the results of the authentication back to you once everything has asynchronously been processed.

The socialbootstrap example shows how to perform posts to /api/auth/{provider} and this causes the browser to redirect to the login screen of the social provider and then back to a redirectUrl in the original app.

I would like to have this work in some kind of popup and the result be passed back to me as some kind of ajax result or a javascript success or failure handler.

Is this possible and if so do you know of any code examples that show this?

My understanding is that iframes are not a universally good way to do this as some social providers have iframe busters...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to support **Credentials** i.e. `UserName/Password` Authentication you could do this via a HTML from in a Popup and ajax.

The https://httpbenchmarks.servicestack.net Live Demo shows an example of this when you click on **Login with your email** button or **Sign In** link (on the top right).

The Authentication/Login process is [documented in detiail the repository](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#logging-in-with-username--password), e.g it uses a modal bootstrap form and [ss-utils bindForm](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ss-utils.js-JavaScript-Client-Library#bootstrap-forms) to ajaxify the HTML Form and provide automatic form and validation binding.

On successful authentication, the `success` callback is fired where you can hide the modal form and run any other post-authentication scripts, e.g:

```
$("#form-login").bindForm({
    success: function (r) {
        $('#modalLogin').modal('hide');
        localStorage["UserName"] = $("[name=UserName]").val();
        $(document).trigger('signed-in');
    }
});
```

Now that the Users Session is authenticated, every subsequent ajax request is sent in the context of the users authenticated session.

If you want to use OAuth then you would need to stick to full-page reloads since often the page will be redirected to the 3rd Party site where the user needs to explicitly allow authentication via your app.